# Web service is giving "illegal refid function"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rpc

We are calling a PHP web service from a Rails app using RPC.  This was working fine.  We had some offshore PHP programmers modify the web service and now this portion of the app throws an error that says `illegal refid function.require-once`.

Having never used RPC before, I am just a tiny bit confused.  This would be an error with the PHP code that the RPC is calling, correct?  I know PHP has a `require_once` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it, but without looking at the actual code (of the web service) and input (your HTTP request), this question cannot be answered.